# 2 проекта по разному определяют разрешение

Tags: android, display

Имеется два проекта. Проект А и Б.
в проекте А и в Б в самом начале метода oncreate есть такой код
Код:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 
Log.d("Resolution", "resolution: "+metrics.widthPixels+" x " 
+ metrics.heightPixels + " dpi " + metrics.densityDpi + " density " + metrics.density 
+ " scaleden " +    metrics.scaledDensity + " xdpi " + metrics.xdpi);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
Log.d("Resolution", "resolution: "+display.getWidth()+" x "+ display.getHeight() 
        + " d " + display.getPixelFormat() );
```

**На одном и том же телефоне**, вывод различается, плотность пикселей для проекта А в полтора раза больше чем для проекта Б!
и изображения проект А открываем в разрешении в полтора раза большем чем есть на самом деле( т.е. вместо 320*240 открывает в разрешении 480*360)
вот пример логов для телефона HTC DISERE V

Проект А:
Код

```
04-04 16:34:35.678: D/Resolution(3636): resolution: 800 x 480 dpi 240 density 1.5 scaleden 1.5 xdpi 234.46153 
04-04 16:34:47.449: D/Resolution(3330): resolution: 800 x 480 d 2
```

Проект Б
Код:

```
04-04 16:17:04.242: D/Resolution(2891): resolution: 533 x 320 dpi 160 density 1.0 scaleden 1.0 xdpi 156.3077 
04-04 16:17:31.108: D/Resolution(2891): resolution: 533 x 320 d 2
```

Кто-нибудь может объяснить такое поведение? я уже всю голову сломал  :cry:

**Разобрался в чем дело! Все дело в этих строчках в манифесте**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion = "10" 
android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

**удалил и все зароботало в проектах одинакого**

Comment: Хм, очень интересно. А targetApi одинаковое? 

Comment: разумеется. Android 2.3.3

Comment: `getDisplayId()`, `getName()` что возвращают? может разные дисплеи... хотя бред канеш.

Comment: getDisplayId() есть в 10 версии API. он в обоих проектах выдает 0.

Comment: Может быть какой-то код измеряет *весь экран*, а другой - только *окно*, в котором находится приложение?

Comment: очень вряд ли. этот код вызsвается в методе onCreate, активити
полностью выглядит вот так:
    public class BluetoothControl extends Activity {
        ....
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Log.d("Resolution", "resolution: "+metrics.widthPixels+" x "
        + metrics.heightPixels + " dpi " + metrics.densityDpi + "         density " + metrics.density
        + " scaleden " + metrics.scaledDensity + " xdpi " +   metrics.xdpi);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ....
      }

т.е. это происходит до вызова setContentView() !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в чем дело! Все дело в этих строчках

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion = "10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Удалил и все зароботало в проектах одинакого

Answer (score 0):

наличие версток во всяких там layout-large может влиять

Comment: не используется  layout-large. шаблоны находятся в папке layaout и они общие для этих проектов